# what is repayment money for renting lets in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, rent, landlord, renter

I am almost about to sign a year's worth of tenancy agreement for a house in London.
There is 4 weeks rent worth of Deposit and 8 weeks rent worth of Repayment to be paid in the beginning of the tenancy. I read a little bit on Repayment order, understanding the the bare minimum of it - it seems like it is there in case a dispute is needed towards unlawful eviction and/or unlicensed multi-tenancy - not seeming like it applies to my situation.

Can someone kindly help with an explanation or personal experience?

Thank you.

Comment: We're going to need to see the relevant text of the agreement. Assured Shorthold Tenancies almost always have a Deposit provision (with suitable protection, which these days is mandatory), typically equal to 1-2 months rent; but I've never seen anything called 'Repayment'.

Comment: Wonder if it is a reaction to the [Queen's Speech suggesting a deposit cap of 1 month](https://www.ft.com/content/80636a80-5697-11e7-9fed-c19e2700005f?mhq5j=e1) (although by the sound of it the "Repayment"  would not be legal if it went ahead)?

Comment: Are you sure it's not "Prepayment" with some rent being due upfront in advance?

Comment: I am assuming it is the money which will be paid back to you unless you breach any of your tenancy conditions.

Comment: @nsandersen yes, without seeing anything else it *sounds* like a sneaky attempt to get round deposit protection rules...